# How to post Image with string using same ajax in php?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to post the image with string(mname) to **sql/enroll_process.php** however the string is echo back successfully onto #response but not work for an image.
I am figuring out  the way to merge both ajax. I just want to receive the name of the image echoing back onto an alert message or #response.

**HTML:**

```
<p id="response"></p>
<form id="enroll_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="mname" name="mname" >
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="pic" name="pic">
<button type="submit"  id="submit_form" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#submit_form').click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();  //prevent page from refresh when click on a button

            var mname = $('#mname').val();

            var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();  // Create a FormData object
            form_data.append('file', file_data);  // Append all element in FormData  object


         if(mname == '' || file_data == '')  {  

                  $('#response').html('<span class="text-danger"> All Fields are required</span>');

             }

             else  
             {  
                      $.ajax({  //ajax for posting text
                           url:"sql/enroll_process.php",  
                           method:"POST",  
                           data:$('#enroll_form').serialize(),  
                           beforeSend:function(){  
                                $('#response').html('<span class="text-info"> Loading response...</span>');  
                           },  
                           success:function(data){  
                                $('form').trigger("reset");  
                                $('#response').fadeIn().html(data);  //receive echo string
                                setTimeout(function(){  
                                     $('#response').fadeOut("slow");  
                                }, 7000);  
                           }  
                      });  


                    $.ajax({ //ajax for posting image
                            url: 'sql/enroll_process.php',  
                            dataType: 'text', 
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            data: form_data,                         
                            type: 'post',
                            success: function(data_g){
                                alert(data_g); //receive & echo image name as string in alert
                            }
                       });  

             }



        });  
   });
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

echo $_POST['mname'];
echo $_FILE['pic']['name'];

?>
```

**Solution:**
Because this question is already answer I cannot post this answer again. I find out the solution. Which send both text and image combined.

```
$(document).on('click','#submit_form',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#enroll_form')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);


    $.ajax({
        url: "sql/enroll_process.php",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
             $('form').trigger("reset");  
                                $('#response').fadeIn().html(data);  
                                setTimeout(function(){  
                                     $('#response').fadeOut("slow");  
                                }, 7000);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You correctly create a FormData object, which is what you need to do, but then you send `form.serialize()` in the request, for some reason. You also need to use `$_FILES` in your PHP to receive the file data. Check any of the duplicates I marked. This is a very popular question.

Comment: Actually, my question is about posting an image with text using ajax. and all the above already mention answers only talking about the code of posting image not text. but thanks again.

Comment: Use a FormData object and append the image and text values.

Comment: ohky I get the solution and I want to post it here can you reopen the question? so that in future me or anybody have the same issue can find the answer here.